# What is django cleaning and validating when you're using form.is_valid, and form.cleaned_data?

Tags: django

So I'm creating a user registration form from a tutorial:

```
def RegisterView(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        new_user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
```

but the tutorial doesn't explain how django is cleaning the data, and how it knows the data is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Your form can have a clean method:

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    # it can be as simple as this
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(YourForm, self).clean()
        name = cleaned_data.get('name')

    # or you can clean specific fields with custom validation logic
    def clean_name(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        name = self.cleaned_data['name']

        if name == 'John':
            msg = 'John is not an acceptable name.'
            self._errors['name'] = self.error_class([msg])
            del cleaned_data['name']
            return name
        return name
```

In your case Django is probably just validating with default logic. For example, if your email field is specified in the models as models.EmailField, then Django is just checking to make sure the input is a valid email address.